# How to parse node value from one node which is reffering from another node in xsl?

Tags: parsing, xslt

Advance thanks for those who will reply bcoz i google it lot but no luck & i am also new in XSL.
**Provided XML**

```
<Parameterdef>
<Anode>
    <Anodeid>1</Anodeid>
</Anode>
<Bnode>
    <Bnodeid>2</Bnodeid>
</Bnode>
<ParameterVisualization>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Anode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Anodeid</Parameter>
    </ParameterDefinition>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Bnode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Bnodeid</Parameter> 
    </ParameterDefinition>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Cnode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Cnodeid</Parameter> 
    </ParameterDefinition>
</ParameterVisualization>
</Parameterdef>
```

Depends on  node value i have to parse hole xml and needs to get the value of that node if that node is exist.

**Require OutPut:**
1,2,N/A(because Cnode is not defined)

Comment: 1) It looks like <code></MLinkParameterDefinition></code> closing element tag is unecessary. 2) How you determines required nodes - are names are constant Anode, Bnode and CNode or the names are defined with text in ParameterVisualization/ParameterDefinition/ParameterSection? 3) What output do you need - text with comma separated list of Id's, List of text nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath functions `name()` and `local-name()` can be used to read the name of an unknown element. These are then compared to element values in a predicate. I'm assuming that the line `</MLinkParameterDefinition>` in your sample code was a typing error and `</ParameterDefinition>` was meant instead. In this solution both `<ParameterSection>` and `<Parameter>` must have a value that matches an element, it also checks that the value of the id-elements must be non-empty.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/ParameterVisualization/ParameterDefinition"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ParameterDefinition">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeId" select="/*/*[local-name() = current()/ParameterSection]
                                            /*[local-name() = current()/Parameter]
                                              [normalize-space()]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$nodeId">
                <xsl:value-of select="$nodeId"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>N/A</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::ParameterDefinition">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output with your (fixed) sample input

```
1,2,N/A
```

No space between commas and no comma after last value.

Somehow I feel like keys should be used in these kind of matching problems, but for me this seemed a more straightforward way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks jasso for your instant reply & your provided solution is  really helpful for me, yes i was done type mistake it should be </ParameterDefinition> now i corrected, can you suggest any good online tutorial for xsl/xslt.

Comment: @Abhijit, This question has listed XSLT tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online  And some guidance on what does "accepting answers" in Stackoverflow mean and how it works can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**This short transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="ParameterDefinition">
   <xsl:variable name="vThis" select="."/>
     <xsl:variable name="vRes" select=
      "/*/*[name()=$vThis/ParameterSection]
                   /*[name()=$vThis/Parameter]
   "/>

   <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">,</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat($vRes,
             substring('N/A',
                       1 div (string-length($vRes) = 0)
                       )
             )"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the (corrected) provided XML document**:

```
<Parameterdef>
<Anode>
    <Anodeid>1</Anodeid>
</Anode>
<Bnode>
    <Bnodeid>2</Bnodeid>
</Bnode>
<ParameterVisualization>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Anode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Anodeid</Parameter>
    </ParameterDefinition>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Bnode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Bnodeid</Parameter>
    </ParameterDefinition>
    <ParameterDefinition>
        <ParameterSection>Cnode</ParameterSection>
        <Parameter>Cnodeid</Parameter>
    </ParameterDefinition>
</ParameterVisualization>
</Parameterdef>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
1,2,N/A
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the standard XPath function **[`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name)**.

Comment: thanks Dimitre Novatchev for your instant reply yes this is also another possible solution thanks again.

Comment: @Abhijit: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Here at SO the official and expected way of expressing gratitude is to accept the best answer -- by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. Please, consider doing this.

Comment: i tried with VoteUp for your answer but it's showing at-least 15 reputation is required anyway can u suggest me any good online stuff for XSL/XSLT

Comment: @Abhijit: In this answer I have provided some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589 . BTW, your rep is > 15 :)